# Python pandas to_sql

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, pandas

Код ниже создает таблицу из DF в БД Oracle, но все строковые поля в базе помещаются в clob. Есть возможность указывать размерность полей при загрузке из датафрейма?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://scott:tiger@tnsname')

tabl.to_sql('RESULT', engine, if_exists='append')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine

dtyp = {c:types.VARCHAR(tabl[c].str.len().max())
        for c in tabl.columns[tabl.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}

tabl.to_sql('RESULT', engine, if_exists='append', dtype=dtyp)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как быть с датой? Ошибка в строке 'date_create': VARCHAR(length=nan)

Comment: @ss_beer, преобразуйте этот столбец в datetime в Pandas